# What Permissions does a user need to upload content into AEM Mobile Cloud service from AEM

Tags: aem, adobe-dps

I have setup a package that I built on an AEM author instance running on my local machine. I have it connecting to the AEM Mobile on demand cloud service.

When I have my package uploaded to a hosted AEM author instance, where I am not able to log in as admin. When I load the mobile project I see an error that the cloud config path does not exist. And I also don't see the 'Upload Shared Resources' button and can't upload articles.

What paths and permissions on those paths does my user need to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to track down the paths and the permissions needed on those paths.

For the cloud config does not exist error the user needs

**read** access to the cloud config path: **/etc/cloudservices/dps2015**

In order to upload the user needs

**read** access to **/etc/contentsync**

and

**read, write, create, delete** access to **/var/contentsync**

and

**read** access to **/var**